# RESET MASTER; does not reset GTID_EXECUTED

Tags: mysql-5.7, percona, master-slave-replication

I'm trying to get replication up and running between two kubernetes pods, and am getting the dreaded `@@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED can only be set when @@GLOBAL.GTID_EXECUTED is empty.` error.

```
root@central-vm:~# mysqldump -u root -h 10.151.0.36 
    --single-transaction --triggers --routines --events --all-databases > alldatabases.sql

root@central-vm:~# mysql -u root -h 10.151.4.69 < alldatabases.sql
ERROR 1840 (HY000) at line 33: @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED can only be set when @@GLOBAL.GTID_EXECUTED is empty.
```

So, I went in to the soon-to-be slave and tried to manually blank it out without any success.

```
Server version: 5.7.26-29-log Percona Server (GPL), Release 29, Revision 11ad961 

mysql> show global variables like 'GTID_EXECUTED';
+---------------+---------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                       |
+---------------+---------------------------------------------+
| gtid_executed | bcf87378-e0d7-11e9-a68e-4e7345ee642a:1-2616 |
+---------------+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> RESET MASTER ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.15 sec)

mysql> show global variables like 'GTID_EXECUTED';
+---------------+------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                    |
+---------------+------------------------------------------+
| gtid_executed | bcf87378-e0d7-11e9-a68e-4e7345ee642a:1-3 |
+---------------+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What am I doing wrong?